# Merge two PDF pages into one showing different halves of each

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a folder of single paged PDF files where I want to merge pairs of two into a new single paged PDF so that always the lower half of each page is not shown. It contains useless information that's why I need to blank it.

[image]

My code is now this but I get it wrong because I need to rotate only one of the input page. But now it seems there are both pages rotated:

(If I could just ***move*** one half it would be great, too)

```
private void clearLowerHalfOfPage(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.WHITE);
    contentStream.addRect(0, 0, 600, 440);
    contentStream.fill();
    contentStream.close();
  }

  public void testMerge() throws IOException {
    File path = new File("/Users/me/Documents/PDF/");
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(path.listFiles());
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size() - 1; i += 2) {
      PDDocument doc1 = PDDocument.load(files.get(i));
      PDDocument doc2 = PDDocument.load(files.get(i + 1));

      clearLowerHalfOfPage(doc2);
      clearLowerHalfOfPage(doc1);

      PDPage page = doc2.getPage(0);
      page.setRotation(180);

      Map<Integer, PDDocument> mapping = new HashMap<>();
      mapping.put(1, doc1);
      Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();
      overlayObj.setInputPDF(doc2);

      PDDocument pdDocument = overlayObj.overlayDocuments(mapping);
      pdDocument.save(new File(path, "x.pdf"));

      pdDocument.close();
      overlayObj.close();
      doc1.close();
      doc2.close();
    }
  }
```

How can I achieve this construction?

Comment: Check out this example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_merging_multiple_pdf_documents.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link but this is just simple appending one PDF to another pdf. I want to merge two pages into one page with hiding one half on both pages.

Comment: Oh, ok I see, sorry for misunderstanding.